# Setting a default payment method using the braintree dropin

Tags: braintree, braintree-sandbox

I am using Braintree to charge customers for their subscriptions (annually). The customer enters his payment method using the Braintree dropin. The payment method is saved and used to pay for the service on a specific date.

Everything works fine until the customer enters another payment method. My backend uses the default payment method to pay for customers services. The problem is that you cannot change the default payment method using the Braintree dropin (setDefault parameter or similar does not exist, although it would be handy).

It has to be done using the backend SDK, where I can call "update" function on PaymentMethod object, like explained [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/update/python). But that is not possible, because to update a payment method you need payment method token which is not available when changing the payment method using the dropin. With dropin only [PaymentMethodNonce](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/payment-method-nonce/python) object is available, which according to documentation does not include payment method token. So it's basically impossible to set some payment method as default using the nonce information.

I'm looking for a way to enable the customer to change his default payment method using the Braintree dropin.

Comment: Have you considered using a [`PaymentMethod.create()`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/create) API request, while specifying the [`make_default`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/create/#options.make_default) option as `true`? That would use the new payment method nonce, store it in the Vault, and make it the default payment method and sounds like what you're hoping to accomplish.

Comment: You are right, it works. It's a bit confusing as "create" method actually acts as "update or create" so the name is obviously misleading. In my case, the drop-in already creates the payment method and returns nonce. And then I send the nonce to my backend, which calls the braintree "create" method with "make_default" parameter that only updates the existing payment method. Exactly what I needed. Put it as an answer, and I'll mark it resolved.